# Mac OS X Opengl output unexpected color. glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0.5) makes 0xff000088 instead of 0xff00007f

Tags: macos, opengl, colors

I am making unit test of OpenGL on Mac OS X using offscreen frame-buffer.
When I performed

```
        glClearColor(1, 0, 0.5, 0.5);
        glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

, it gives me `0xFF008080` instead of `0xFF007F7F` for each pixels. It's confusing why this result came out. The only thing I can figure out is color-calibration, but in that case, I don't know how to handle this to expect right result. (and even, what's the *right* result? corrected color? or raw color?)

Here're my questions.

1. What should I expect when using OpenGL. Corrected color? or raw color?
2. When is the correction pass being performed? After fragment shader? After color written to framebuffer?
3. Is there a way to test raw color?
4. Can I access color correction feature to reproduce the result?

Here's full source code for reference.

```
- (void)test_1000_createContext
{
    NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute    pfa[1]  =   { 0 };
    NSOpenGLPixelFormat*    pixelFormat     =   [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:pfa];

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSOpenGLContext*        GL              =   [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:pixelFormat shareContext:nil];
        [GL makeCurrentContext];
        {
            ASS (GL != nil);

            GLuint  fb;
            GLuint  rbc;
            glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
            glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbc);
            ASS (fb !=0 );
            ASS (rbc != 0);

            GLint w, h;
            w = 2;
            h = 2;

            glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbc);
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
            glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, w, h);
            glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbc);
            glClearColor(1, 0, 0.5, 0.5);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glFinish();

            uint8_t*    buffer      =   malloc(4*w*h);
            glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
            NSData* bdat    =   [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:4*w*h freeWhenDone:YES];
            NSLog(@"%@", bdat);

            uint8_t     answer[]    =
            {
                0xFF, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x7F,
                0xFF, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x7F,
                0xFF, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x7F,
                0xFF, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x7F,
            };
            ASS (memcmp(answer, buffer, 4*4) == 0 );
        }
        [NSOpenGLContext clearCurrentContext];
    }

}
```

Comment: There's nothing I can think of that can cause this. I don't think there's any such concept as *color correction* in OpenGL (at least not enabled by default). Have you tried any other values than 0.5? Is it only the alpha channel that's off or are all the channels the same?

Comment: @Tim It's same over all channels. I updated my question. I set blue to `0.5F`, now blue is also `0x88`.

Comment: maybe this has to do with premultiplied vs. non-premultiplied alpha?

Comment: @nielsbot If there's such thing, it could because of it. How can I get the current mode and set it?

Comment: Your buffer only have four bits per component, so some clamping/conversion will occur. What happens if you use GL_RGBA8 as internal format for your renderbuffer?

Comment: @Plow OK. I thought you finally found it! But unfortunately, it was not because of it. I fixed it to `GL_RGBA8` and not it gives me `0xFF008080` which is a little more accurate result in that unknown algorithm's basis. I updated my question to apply these values.

Comment: And when I run this test code on iOS, it gave me correct result `0xFF007F7F`. Even it was tested with `GL_RGBA4`. So I missed it, but problem still continues on Mac after I fixed it to 8 bit... :(

Comment: Note that 0.5 is not exactly representable with 8 bits either. 7F/FF = 0.498, 80/FF = 0.502.